# Setting up eclipse for scala development with Maven

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I am trying to setup Scala development environment with maven(for builds) on eclipse. I was trying to follow the instructions from http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/index.html

As a first step, I need to install the m2eclipse-scala plugin from http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site/ . After a lot of struggle with my proxy settings, I was finally able to get it working and installed the components from the update site.

For the second step, I tried to create a new maven project with scala archetype. But, I still don't find the scala archetype in the list of archetypes. 
Below is the list of archetypes that show up when I try to create a new maven project:

[image]

Below is the list of installed components:

[image]

I believe I've installed all the required components. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.